Como podria obtener los numeros de la semana
Tengo una situacion, necesito traer el numero de semana del año, pero no solo del actual, ya que puede que se nececiten datos de las ultimas semanas del año pasado, yo ya obtengo la cantidad de semana trascurridas del año actual, pero como mencione, que tal si necesita traer datos del año pasado
const WeekNumber = date => {
        const day_to_milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        weekdays = 7,
        thursday = 4;
        date = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()));
        let dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay(); // Domingo es 0, sábado es 6
        if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
            dayOfWeek = 7;
        }
        date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() - dayOfWeek + thursday);
        const begginYear = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
        const difference = date - begginYear;
        return Math.ceil(((difference / day_to_milliseconds) + 1) / weekdays);
    }

asi es como yo obtendo la semana actual
function weeksNumbers(){
        let date = new Date()
        let week = WeekNumber(date)
        let array = []
        let numberWeek = 1
        for (numberWeek; numberWeek <= week; numberWeek++) {
            let itm = {
                label: numberWeek.toString(),
                value: numberWeek
            }
            array.push(itm)            
        }
        //console.log(array)
        setWeeks(array)
    }

y asi como creo las semana trascurridas

¿Qué problema hay con pasar el año que necesitás como parámetro?

@padaleiana La pregunta no está bien redactada, no es un problema de pasar o no datos como argumentos. El problema es que su for siempre va desde 1 hasta el número de semana actual y de la forma en que la OP ha creado el algoritmo, no es posible ir desde la semana 30 del año anterior hasta la semana actual, porque no contempla nunca el año y porque no tiene ningún mecanismo que cuando se desborde en la semana 52 (o 53 según el caso) pase a la semana 1 del año siguiente

Para obtener el número de semana según una fecha puedes hacer lo siguiente:
const date = new Date(2023, 11, 20);
const numero = WeekNumber(date);
// El número de semana que devuelve esta fecha es el 51

En este ejemplo la fecha es el 20 de diciembre de 2023. En este caso se pasa el 11 como mes porque para ese constructor el 0 significa enero y el 11 es diciembre.
Espero te sirva.

Un número de la semana, por ejemplo 32 no es un dato muy bueno, todos los años tienen semana 32, por tanto, siempre es necesario acompañar del año correspondiente.
Por ejemplo, los input type="week" retorna algo como 2024-W54. En tu caso es especialmente importante, porque requieres calcular la cantidad de semanas entre 2 fechas desde y hasta que pueden estar en años distintos.
Yo crearía una clase Semana que sería un nuevo tipo de dato para manipular semanas (el nombre lo decía :P). Que internamente tendrá un input type="week" el cual facilitará los cálculos


class Semana {
    #input;
    constructor(date) {
        this.#input = document.createElement('input');
        this.#input.type = 'week';
        this.#input.valueAsDate = date;
    }
    valueOf() {
        return Number(this.#input.value.replace("-W", ""));
    }
    addSemana(cant) {
        const fecha = this.#input.valueAsDate;
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + cant * 7);
        this.#input.valueAsDate = fecha;
    }
    get value() {
        const [year, week] = this.#input.value.split('-W').map(Number);
        return {
            label: this.#input.value,
            year: year,
            week: week
        }
    }
}

Date.prototype.GetWeek = function() {
  return new Semana(this);
}

function weeksNumbers(desde, hasta=new Date()) {
  let semanaHasta = hasta.GetWeek();

  let array = []
  for (let s = new Semana(desde); s <= semanaHasta; s.addSemana(1)) {
     array.push(s.value);
  }
  console.log(array); 
}

weeksNumbers(new Date("2023-12-12"));



Explicación de la Clase Semana

Incorpora un input type="week", donde su value retorna un string del tipo 2032-W32 y valueAsDate una fecha de tipo Date con el primer día de la semana

valueOf Es una función que retorna un número, por ejemplo 203232 que es la concatenación del año+semana, esto es útil para comparar fechas (con mayor, menor o igual) y se utiliza para poder realizar un for

addSemana Una función que permite sumar (o restar) semanas a la semana actual

value() retorna un objeto con datos de la semana


Luego:

Date.prototype.GetWeek añade una nueva funcion GetWeek a los Date, que retorna la clase Semana

